# Overriding the HttpClientFactory policies defined with Polly

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, polly, resiliency

From .net Core 2+ MS gave us a way to add policies to the HttpClient that will work as long as the client is injected through the IOC container. But this led me to a doubt I can't seem to figure out while endlessly googling. What if we want to override the HttpClient policies while still using the HttpClientFactory and DI to inject the client into a provider? Can we "turn off" the policies for a specific request or can we add extra Policies while overriding the global ones defined on the Startup ?

Comment: Edited my original answer to highlight a way that this is possible

Answer (score 4):

Use different [named clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#named-clients) or [typed clients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-2.1#typed-clients) to define separate logical `HttpClient` configurations.

*OR*

When configuring policies using `IHttpClientFactory`, you can use [`.AddPolicyHandler(...)` overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pollyhttpclientbuilderextensions.addpolicyhandler) or [`.AddPolicyHandlerFromRegistry(...)` overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.pollyhttpclientbuilderextensions.addpolicyhandlerfromregistry) which allow you to select the policy based on information in the `HttpRequestMessage`.  This can permit varying the policies applied for different requests.

To take an example from the [Polly and HttpClientFactory documentation](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Polly-and-HttpClientFactory#selecting-policies-dynamically), one use case might be to apply a Retry policy only to GET requests but not other http verbs:

```
var retryPolicy = HttpPolicyExtensions
    .HandleTransientHttpError()
    .WaitAndRetryAsync(new[]
    {
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)
    });
var noOpPolicy = Policy.NoOpAsync().AsAsyncPolicy<HttpResponseMessage>();

services.AddHttpClient(/* etc */)
    // Select a policy based on the request: retry for Get requests, noOp for other http verbs.
    .AddPolicyHandler(request => request.Method == HttpMethod.Get ? retryPolicy : noOpPolicy);
```

Comment: Thats not quite what I was looking for but its probably what I will have to use. I wanted to , while injecting a TypedClient override the policies that are alredy on this typed client and then use whatever I want for a given scope.